# HTML image doesn't show up on mobile web browser

Tags: android, html, mobile

I'm tinkering with HTML for the first time and am running into an issue.  In this very basic page, my image shows up just fine on my PC.  I've transferred the file to my Samsung tablet and the image doesn't load. The HTML file and the GIF are saved in the same folder on my tablet.  This works fine using Chrome/Firefox on my laptop. I assumed I was using the same browser on my tablet. Is there a tag I need to add for use on mobile devices?

Thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Image Map</title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="Dial_face.png" alt="Image Map" border="0" width="300" height="300">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Think that gifs are not supported. Try with a jpg or png. Show code how you load the file. You did not even tell in which app you are loading and viewing  the html file.

Comment: I changed the image to png.  I opened the file using Chrome on my Samsung tablet.

Comment: How are you opening that html file in Chrome? Chrome usually does not get in the open list for a html file.

Comment: I tap the file and it asks me which browser to use.  I select Chrome and it opens.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce it but since it's very basic, I'll try a wild guess:
1) Check the image name for proper uppercase and lowercase letters - they must match exactly.
2) Remove the `usemap="#map1"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If the error persist, check the image permission (*Dial_face.png*) and set them with 775 or 777.

Comment: The error persists.  This works fine using Chrome/Firefox on my laptop.  I assumed I was using the same browser on my tablet.  Is there a tag I need to add for use on mobile devices?